# on_starting or someting like - Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I just want to know if there is something like "on_starting" with Asyncio

Example :

````py
import asyncio

async def on_starting():
    print("Starting ...")

async def on_ready():
    print("successfully starting")```
````

Comment: When are you wanting it to run? On the start of the program?

Comment: Not really, in fact I want that when I launch the program, it starts automatically, during the loading

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    print('event loop started')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


print('event loop starting')
asyncio.run(main())
print('event loop finished')
```

Does this answer your question?